# Missing SDCard in android emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device, ddms, android-sdcard

I have a "simple" question. I created AVD with SDCard, but when I use in eclipse DDMS -> File explorer I dont see a folder named SDCard. I see only mnt/sdcard - is this a SDCard folder?

Thanks

Marcus

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and in your case the /sdcard is just a Linux symbol link to the /mnt/sdcard folder.

Regards

Ziteng Chen